# Reconocer variables de una cadena que esta definida como string Angular.js [1.6]

Tags: angularjs

Como puedo lograr lo siguiente
..

```
$scope.id = 2;
$scope.name = 'jhon';
$scope.render = "<b>{{id}} - {{name}}</b>";
..
<p ng-bind-html='render'></p>
```

En php existe algo como esto
printf('texto y demas %s mas texto de relleno %s un poco mas.', $var1, $var2);
lo cual también seria bueno si existiera en angularjs para obtener el resultado deseado.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: gracias es mi primer pregunta, ahorita lo reviso, muy amable

Answer (score 0):

Si esta usando ES6 podrias hacer algo asi

```
$scope.id = 2;
$scope.name = 'jhon';
$scope.render = `<b>${id} - ${name}</b>`;
..
<p ng-bind-html='render'></p>
```

A esto se le llama `Text Interpolation` por si quieres hacer una búsqueda mas profunda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente forma

```
if (!String.prototype.fprintFormat) {
    String.prototype.fprintFormat = function() {
        return [...arguments].reduce((p,c) => p.replace(/%s/,c), this);
    };
}
```

y para llamarlo, de la siguiente manera:
ng-bind-html="col.render.fprintFormat(row[value1]))"